# Comparison operator substitution for IF from FOR cycle in batch scripts

Tags: if-statement, for-loop, batch-file

I would like to ask your help in a possibly simple situation (where the solution is yet unknown for me).

I am trying to provide a variable for the if command to make a bit more "dynamic" the code, but this fails for me with:
% was unexpected at this time.

Here is a simple example for that:

```
> for %i in (NEQ) do (if 1 %i 2 echo jo)
%i was unexpected at this time.
```

While the following works like charm:

```
>set oper=NEQ
>for %i in (NEQ) do (if 1 %oper% 2 echo works)
works
```

As I should stay in the for loop (and I get the actual operator from the for loop in the real code), I am really stuck how to solve it...

Tried to play with EnableDelayedExpansion as well, but !variable! instead of the operator is refused as well. Is there a way to submit the variable in a FOR loop for IF, without major modifications in the script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to submit the variable in a FOR loop for IF?

No!
Because, the `IF` statement has it's own parser and it expects some tokens already expanded at this parse phase.
So it's neither possible to expand the options nor the operator, nor `NOT`.
But it's allowed to expand the values with delayed or FOR-variables.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set myOperator=EQU
IF 1 %myOperator% 1 echo Works
IF 1 !myOperator! 1 echo FAILS
for %%O in (EQU) do IF 1 %%O 1 echo Works
```

The percent expansion works, as it is expanded before the `IF` parser gets the line.

If you really need to use variable operators, then you need to use a function.

```
for %%O in (EQU) do call :myFunc %%O
exit /b

:myFunc 
IF ONE %1 ONE echo Works
exit /b
```

**EDIT:**
And the special parser is also the cause, that it's not possible to use here a `CALL` expansion for the `IF` statement.

Like this idea

```
set myOperator=EQU
CALL IF 1 %%myOperator%% 1 echo Works
```

This should expand to `IF 1 EQU 1 echo Works`, but the combination of `CALL` and `IF` fails always.

Comment: Thank you for the information, I was not aware of it. I will try to use the advised function method, thank you again. (Not sure if the first code works, for me it fails out at the 4th row, and cannot proceed to the 5th. If I REM out the 4th, the 5th fails out.)

Comment: Yes, the 4th and 5th line can't work, as both create a syntax error. The `IF` parser can't handle `!myOperator!` nor `%%O` so it throws the error.

Comment: To not alter greatly the original code (the one I shared was a simplification of the original code only to indicate my problem) I have modified it to use another FOR command. For the example it is something like:

`for %i in (NEQ) do (
  for /F %x in ('if 1 %i 2 echo works') do (echo works)
)`

Comment: In the case of `for /f %x in 'if 1 %i 2 echo works') ...` it works, as the expansion of %i will occur before the `if` is parsed, because the complete `if %i 2 echo ...` is executed in a new cmd thread